# JAX-WS: SOAP: implement server Basic Authentification with JRE only

Tags: soap, jax-ws, basic-authentication

I've already implemented a JAX-WS with Java 8 runtime.
Now I need to add the basic authentication support at both client and server sides:

1. I do know how to manually add the 'Authorization: Basic ...' header at the client side, but I want the client to add it when it receives the 401 response from the server only;
2. I do NOT know how to make the server to check this header value and return the 401 response if this header is missing or the credential check is not passed;
3. I need the implementation based on JRE only (no Tomcat, Weblogic, Glassfish etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you might already solved your problem I want to provide a sample implementation if someone else have some use for it.

Server:

```
javax.xml.ws.Endpoint serverEndpoint = Endpoint.create(new MyService());

com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);

com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpContext httpContext = server.createContext("/myservice");

server.start();

AuthenticatorServer authenticatorServer = new AuthenticatorServer("myRealm", "myName", "myPwd");

httpContext.setAuthenticator(authenticatorServer);  

serverEndpoint.publish(httpContext);
```

Where AuthenticatorServer is:

```
private static class AuthenticatorServer extends com.sun.net.httpserver.BasicAuthenticator {

    private final String user;
    private final String pwd;

    public AuthenticatorServer(String realm, String user, String pwd) {
        super(realm);
        this.user = user;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkCredentials(String userNameInput, String passwordInput) {

        return StringUtils.equals(user, userNameInput) && StringUtils.equals(pwd, passwordInput);

    }

}
```

And on the Client side:

```
AuthenticatorClient authenticatorClient = new AuthenticatorClient("myName", "myPwd");

Authenticator.setDefault(authenticatorClient);

javax.xml.namespace.QName qName = new QName(namespaceURI, WS_SERVICE_NAME);
java.net.URL wsdlAddress = new URL(namespaceURI + WS_SERVICE_NAME + "?wsdl");

MyService service =(Service.create(wsdlAddress, qName)).getPort(MyService.class);
```

Where AuthenticatorClient is:

```
private static class AuthenticatorClient extends java.net.Authenticator {

    private final String user;
    private final String pwd;

    public AuthenticatorClient(String user, String pwd) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication(user, pwd == null ? null : pwd.toCharArray()));
    }

}
```